# Proof of Doob's decomposition theorem?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[image]

I feel confused about the proof of the theorem.

**First question:**
Why in step 2, $Z_{n+1}=E(X_{n+1}|F_n)-X_n+Z_n$, then we can get $Z_{n+1}$ is $F_n$ measurable? I can see $E(X_{n+1}|F_n)$ and $X_n$ are $F_n$ measurable, but how $Z_n$ is $F_n$ measurable?

**Second question:**

I didn't see the proof of $E(Z_n)< \infty$? How to conclude that from $Z_{n+1}=E(X_{n+1}|F_n)-X_n+Z_n$?

Thanks so much! Your help will be appreciated!:)

Comment: Answer: Induction (to both Questions).